# Animate a Java Line drawing using a timer

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I am trying to draw two circle on a panel with a line joining them, all after a button is pressed. So far (apart from tweaking locations of the line) this is ok. However, I would like to animate it using a timer. The first circle should appear, then gradually the line will be revealed, and finally the second circle.

I have looked at many examples of timers, but I can't seem to get it to work for me. I must be misunderstanding something.

here is the ball class (for each circle):

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Ball {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int r;
    private Color color;
    private Point location;
    private Ball parent;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        setLocation(p);
    }

    public void setParent(Ball b) {
        parent = b;
    }

    public Ball getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setx(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void sety(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getx() {
        return x;
    }

    public int gety() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getr() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setPreferedSize() {

    }

    public void setLocation(Point p) {
        setx(p.x);
        sety(p.y);
        location = p;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

then the class that will store balls in an arrayList. And I think that this is where the actual drawing should take place, along with the timer.
I am trying to set the start and end point of the line to be the same, and increment the end point until it is where it should be, using the timer. I'm probably way of track, but that was the intention!

I have change this class, the if statements in the while loop can now be entered, as I am now comparing different point. But the line doesn't get drawn at all still.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BallsArray extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private ArrayList<Ball> balls;
    private Timer timer;
    private final int DELAY = 25;
    private int xDest;
    private int yDest;
    private Point dest;
    private Point starts;
    private int xStart;
    private int yStart;

    public BallsArray() {
        balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        yDest = 0;
        xDest = 0;
        dest = new Point(xDest, yDest);
        starts = new Point(xStart, yStart);

    }

    public void setDestXY(int x, int y) {
        xDest = x;
        yDest = y;
        dest = new Point(xDest, yDest);
        setDest(dest);
    }

    public void setDest(Point p) {
        dest = p;

    }

    public Point getDest() {
        return dest;
    }

    public void setStartsXY(int x, int y) {
        xStart = x;
        yStart = y;
        starts = new Point(xStart, yStart);
        setStarts(starts);
    }

    public void setStarts(Point p) {
        starts = p;
    }

    public Point getStarts() {
        return starts;
    }

    public void addBall(Ball b) {
        balls.add(b);
    }

    public void addBall(int x, int y, int r) {
        balls.add(new Ball(x, y, r));

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                paintBall(balls.get(0), g2);
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                int j = i - 1;
                Ball bp = balls.get(j);
                Ball bc = balls.get(i);
                bc.setParent(bp);
                paintLine(bc, g2);
                paintBall(bc, g2);
            }

        }
    }

    public void paintBall(Ball b, Graphics2D g2d) {
        Ellipse2D circ = new Ellipse2D.Float(b.getx(), b.gety(), b.getr(),
                b.getr());
        g2d.draw(circ);
    }

    public void paintLine(Ball b, Graphics2D g2d) {
        timer.start();
        if (b != null && b.getLocation() != null) {
            Ball parent = b.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                if (parent.getLocation() != null && b.getLocation() != null) {
                    setDest(parent.getLocation());
                    setStarts(parent.getLocation());
                    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(starts, dest));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Not sure what I need to do here
        // increment second location somehow
        // Point s = getStarts();
        Point p = getDest();
        Point t = this.getLocation();
        while (p != t) {

            if (p.x != t.x && p.y != t.y) {
                System.out.println("hello");
                int x = dest.x;
                int y = dest.y;
                x++;
                y++;
                setDestXY(x, y);
                p = getDest();
                repaint();
            } else if (p.x == t.x && p.y != t.y) {
                System.out.println("part 2");
                int y = dest.y;
                y++;
                setDestXY(dest.x, y);
                p = getDest();
                repaint();
            } else if (p.x != t.x && p.y == t.y) {
                System.out.println("part 3");
                int x = dest.x;
                x++;
                setDestXY(x, dest.y);
                p = getDest();
                repaint();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I have had a lot of help online getting this far, I worry I am just beyond my depth now!. I am unsure about the EventQueue/run part below. Here is the class to set it all up:

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private BallsArray b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display ex = new Display();

            }
        });

    }

    public Display() {
        b = new BallsArray();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Show balls");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button = new JButton("New Ball");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Ball ball1 = new Ball(100, 100, 50);
        b.addBall(ball1);
        b.addBall(200, 200, 50);
        frame.add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();

    }
}
```

At the moment it draws the two circles, but not the line at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an animation, it helps to use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Here's the GUI I created from your code.

[image: Show Balls Animation]

I simplified your Ball class.  This is all you need to define a ball.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Ball {

    private final int radius;

    private final Color color;

    private final Point center;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int radius, Color color) {
        this(new Point(x, y), radius, color);
    }

    public Ball(Point center, int radius, Color color) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

}
```

I created the GUIModel class to hold all of the information your GUI needs.  This separates the model from the view.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GUIModel {

    private double direction;
    private double distance;

    private List<Ball> balls;

    private Point lineStartPoint;
    private Point lineEndPoint;

    public GUIModel() {
        this.balls = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addBall(Ball ball) {
        this.balls.add(ball);
    }

    public List<Ball> getBalls() {
        return balls;
    }

    public void calculatePoints() {
        this.lineStartPoint = balls.get(0).getCenter();
        this.lineEndPoint = balls.get(1).getCenter();

        this.distance = Point.distance(lineStartPoint.x, lineStartPoint.y,
                lineEndPoint.x, lineEndPoint.y);
        this.direction = Math.atan2(lineEndPoint.y - lineStartPoint.y,
                lineEndPoint.x - lineStartPoint.x);
    }

    public Point getCurrentPoint(int pos, int total) {
        double increment = distance / total;
        double length = increment * pos;

        double x = lineStartPoint.x + Math.cos(direction) * length;
        double y = lineStartPoint.y - Math.sin(direction) * length;

        x = Math.round(x);
        y = Math.round(y);

        return new Point((int) x, (int) y);
    }

    public Point getLineStartPoint() {
        return lineStartPoint;
    }

}
```

This class holds the two Ball instances, and calculates the length and direction of the line, divided into total increments.

Now that we've defined the model classes, let's look at the view classes.  The first is your Display class.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display implements Runnable {

    private GUIModel guiModel;

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Display());
    }

    public Display() {
        this.guiModel = new GUIModel();
        Ball ball1 = new Ball(150, 200, 50, Color.BLUE);
        Ball ball2 = new Ball(450, 200, 50, Color.GREEN);
        guiModel.addBall(ball1);
        guiModel.addBall(ball2);
        guiModel.calculatePoints();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Show Balls Animation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(guiModel);
        panel.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.add(createButtonPanel(drawingPanel), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start Animation");
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartAnimation(drawingPanel));
        panel.add(startButton);

        return panel;
    }

    public class StartAnimation implements ActionListener {

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        public StartAnimation(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            LineRunnable runnable = new LineRunnable(drawingPanel);
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }

    }

}
```

The constructor of the Display class sets up the GUI model.

The run method of the Display class constructs the GUI, and starts the animation.

See how I've separated the model and view.

The StartAnimation class is your controller.  It starts the animation when you left click on the JButton.  I'll discuss the LineRunnable class later.

Next, let's take a look at the DrawingPanel class.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3709678584255542338L;

    private boolean drawLine;

    private int pos;
    private int total;

    private GUIModel guiModel;

    public DrawingPanel(GUIModel guiModel) {
        this.guiModel = guiModel;
        this.drawLine = false;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    }

    public boolean isDrawLine() {
        return drawLine;
    }

    public void setDrawLine(boolean drawLine) {
        this.drawLine = drawLine;
    }

    public void setPos(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (Ball ball : guiModel.getBalls()) {
            g2d.setColor(ball.getColor());
            Point center = ball.getCenter();
            int radius = ball.getRadius();
            g2d.fillOval(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius + radius,
                    radius + radius);
        }

        if (isDrawLine()) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0F));
            Point a = guiModel.getLineStartPoint();
            Point b = guiModel.getCurrentPoint(pos, total);
            g2d.drawLine(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
        }
    }

}
```

The only thing this view class does is draw the balls and the line.  The responsibility for calculating the length of the line belongs in the model.

I set the preferred size here, and use the pack method in the Display class to get the size of the JFrame.  You usually want to know the dimensions of the drawing area, rather than the entire window.

Finally, let's look at the LineRunnable class.  This is the class that controls the animation.

```
package twoBalls;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class LineRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int total;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    public LineRunnable(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
        this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        this.total = 240;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setDrawLine();
        for (int pos = 0; pos <= total; pos++) {
            setPos(pos);
            sleep(50L);
        }
    }

    private void setDrawLine() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawingPanel.setDrawLine(true);
                drawingPanel.setTotal(total);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setPos(final int pos) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawingPanel.setPos(pos);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sleep(long delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

In the run method, we divide the line into 240 segments, and draw a segment every 50 milliseconds.  It takes the GUI 12 seconds to draw the line.  You can play with these numbers if you wish.

The for loop is a classic animation loop.  First you update the model, which I'm doing through the drawing panel.  Then you sleep.

This animation loop is running on a different thread from the GUI thread.  This keeps the GUI responsive.  Since the loop is running on a different thread, we have to use the invokeLater method to draw on the Event Dispatch thread.

I hope this was helpful to you.  Divide and conquer.  Don't let a class do more than one thing.

Comment: Thank you! This is helping me so much, especially your explanations. If I wanted to make it so that the balls aren't draw until the button is clicked, would I change the paintComponent method in the DrawingPanel class so that the balls painting were in another if statement?

Comment: @Ash: Yes.  I'd use another boolean to signal to the paintComponent method when to draw the balls.